# Install Whonix on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: debian, ubuntu, virtualbox, backports, whonix

I followed the instructions for installing Whonix on Linux and I got stuck at installing Virtualbox from Debian backports. I get the following errors after step 3 ([here](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VirtualBox)):

```
W: GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
E: The repository 'http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried to replace the recommended line

```
sudo su -c "echo -e 'deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main contrib' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list"
```

with

```
sudo su -c "echo -e 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list"
```

I got that information from the Debian website:
https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

*Note:*
I removed the old backports.list before adding the new with following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

Well I get quite the same error with the recommended instructions on the Debian site. I wonder now, what to do. Can't I just install virtualbox from the Ubuntu repo? It's a little confusing, since the references on the [whonix page](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VirtualBox) at the end of the line "Package virtualbox should be installed from Debian backports." are not working. The browser is just jumping at the top of the site.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are for Debian. Backports only required in case of Debian since VirtualBox is unavailable in stretch.

Please install VirtualBox using the usual mechanisms of your Linux distribution.